# Appending one truth table to another

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

So I need to generate a truth table for a bunch of different functions (like implies, not p and q, not p and q, and, or, etc.)

I have a recursive method that generates the first two terms of each index correctly ([False, False], [False, True], [True, False], [True, True]).
However what I need to do is take those two terms and then append the result of those two from one of the different functions to the end of the indices.

make_tt_ins(n): My recursive table builder with n rows (in this case two)
and callf2(f, p, q): a given function that generates the True / False term I'll need to append onto each index.

```
my_list = PA1.make_tt_ins(2)

p = True;
q = True;

val = [callf2(f, p, q)]

returnVal = [i + val for i in my_list]

return returnVal
```

Obviously, all I'm getting is True after my intial two values in each index. I just don't know how to correctly append the callf2 function result onto my first two values in each index.

For the function implies (p <-> q), I'm getting:

```
[[False, False, True], [False, True, True], [True, False, True], [True, True, True]]

It should look something like:
[[False, False, True], [False, True, False], [True, False, False], [True, True, True]]
```

Comment: Don’t you just want to call `callf2(f,*i)`?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. To anyone wondering, I decided to use one massive while loop with a counter where at each step I would set p / q to different True/False values and then run them with the callf2 function. I then turned those values in a list, which I appended onto my first partial list.